# Realm: Best practice to link object with a property associated with the link

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Say we have an object `A` and we want to link it with a sortable list of `Publications`. But also, we have another object `B` which also has a sortable list of `Publications`. `Publication` objects may be shared between the lists.

Sorting order is defined in the backend and results in some integer property `sort`.  Obviously, we cannot store this property as part of `Publication` object, because its’ sorting order is different in relation to different objects (`A` & `B`) and we’ll just needlessly update these objects every time we update lists, resulting in unwanted notifications.

I see a couple of ways to achieve this:

1. In SQL world, we can make many-to-many link via an intermediary table, where we can also store some properties, associated with a link, like `sort`. We can do something like this with Realm, but it’s a bit inconvenient and feels like API misuse.
2. We can make another `List` property with sorting order for the list stored in it. Though it’s even more inconvenient and strange.

Thanks in advance for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I concluded that this way feels as the most natural one, if you only want an ordered list of dependencies:

1. Make a `List` of ordered primary keys for the entity you want to "join".
2. Throw in some accessors to fetch necessary objects.

Still clumsy and you can't query dependencies.